# When to use auxiliary recursive functions/methods for recursive functions/methods

Tags: scala, recursion

In a worksheet for a functional programming course, I was asked to write a function in Scala (though I think the prof may have meant method) that recursively prints elements in a list on a new line with a line number with a result like this:

```
    scala> printCounter (List ("the", "rain", "in", "spain"))
[001] the
[002] rain
[003] in
[004] spain
```

The solution provided on the worksheet looks like this:

```
def printCounterAux [X] (xs:List[X], count:Int) : Unit = {
  xs match {
    case Nil   => ()
    case y::ys => {
      println ("[%03d] %s".format (count, y))
      printCounterAux (ys, count + 1)
    }
  }
}

def printCounter [X] (xs:List[X]) : Unit = {
  printCounterAux (xs, 1)
}

printCounter (List ("the", "rain", "in", "spain"))
```

It had not occurred to me to create an auxiliary method. My question, as someone who is still getting a handle on recursion, is: how do you know when it is necessary to create an auxiliary recursive method? In this case would the signal be multiple parameters? Or is it simply a matter of lots of exposure to these kinds of methods? Thanks very much for any advice you can share. Cheers.

Comment: Notice how you can call `printCounter(myList)` with a single argument but `printCounterAux` is called with `myList` _and_ a number, `1` in this case. This is nice because the caller of the function doesn't have to remember to send `1` along as the second argument each time. You don't _need_ the auxiliary function, but without, the caller would need to supply the initial `1`. In general an auxiliary function is used when the loop's arguments are not the same as the arguments expected at the call site.

Comment: Actually that auxiliary function should have been declared inside the main one, that way it would have been effectively private to the external world. Answering your question, your main _(public)_ function should not expose internal details, like the line number, it should only receive what it has to receive and return what is has to return, but for the implementation, you may need some extra arguments for keeping state, so you create a new aux function which is meant for internal use only, and your main function calls that function with the correct initial values.

Comment: Basically, you will be doing that almost every time you want to create a _(tail)_ recursive function.

Comment: Another thing you can consider is using a [default parameter value](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html). In many cases this can remove the need for an auxiliary function, but be aware that the caller can override the default values at the call site. For example, you could write `def printCounter [X] (xs:List[X], count: Int = 1): Unit = { ... }` and when you call `printCounter(myList)`, `count` will default to `1`. However if you were to call `printCounter(myList, 10)` `count` will start at `10` and you will get a somewhat unexpected result.

Comment: I have [many posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:633183+[recursion]) on the topic of recursion in the context of functional programming. I think you probably find them quite helpful :D

Comment: @ThankYou a default value still exposes internal details to the outside, as well as giving the user the possibility of compute a bad answer. It may do the job, but is a bad design and I won't suggest it to a newcomer.

Comment: @Luis, I did caution the value can be overridden at the call site but in some situations it's perfectly okay. Eg, `def search[X](xs:List[X], q: X, pos: Int = 0)...` where `search(myList, foo)` would start the search at the 0th element (beginning of the list), and `search(myList, foo, 3)` starts at the 3rd element.

Comment: @Thankyou oh yeah I forgot a "_(as you said)_" in my comment, sorry. And I did not say a default argument was always a bad idea, effectively in your example it is, but because it is not internal state, it is another parameter of the function, the start search index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s common in Scala to write
functions that are local to the body
of another function. In functional
programming, we shouldn’t consider
this a bigger deal than local integers
or strings.

The way we write loops functionally, without mutating a loop variable, is with a recursive
function. Here we’re defining a recursive helper function inside the body of the
factorial function. Such a helper function is often called go or loop by convention.

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    def go(n: Int, acc: Int): Int =
        if (n <= 0) acc
        else go(n - 1, n * acc)
    go(n, 1)
}
```

Since it’s local, the go function can only be referred to from within the
body of the factorial function, just like a local variable would. The definition of
factorial finally just consists of a call to go with the initial conditions for the loop.

The arguments to go are the state for the loop. In this case, they’re the remaining
value n, and the current accumulated factorial acc. To advance to the next iteration,
we simply call go recursively with the new loop state (here, `go(n-1, n*acc))`, and to
exit from the loop, we return a value without a recursive call (here, we return acc in
the case that `n <= 0`). Scala detects this sort of self-recursion and compiles it to the same
sort of bytecode as would be emitted for a while loop(we can write while loops by hand in Scala, but it’s rarely necessary and considered bad form since it hinders
good compositional style.), so long as the recursive call is
in tail position.

A call is said to be in tail position if the caller does nothing other than return the value
of the recursive call. For example, the recursive call to `go(n-1,n*acc)` is in tail position, 
since the method returns the value of this recursive call directly
and does nothing else with it. On the other hand, if we said `1 + go(n-1,n*acc)`, go function
would no longer be in tail position, since the method would still have work to do when
go returned its result (namely, adding 1 to it).
If all recursive calls made by a function are in tail position, Scala automatically compiles
the recursion to iterative loops that don’t consume call stack frames for each
iteration and we can avoid StackOverflow issues. By default, Scala doesn’t tell us if tail call elimination was successful, but
if we’re expecting this to occur for a recursive function we write, we can tell the Scala
compiler about this assumption using the tailrec annotation , so it can give us a compile error if it’s unable to eliminate the tail calls of the
function.

```
def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(n: Int, acc: Int): Int =
        if (n <= 0) acc
        else go(n - 1, n * acc)
    go(n, 1)
}
```

This is a very common scenario to write an inner function, or local definition.

Answer (score 1):

`printCounterAux` has a different API than `printCounter`. Not only that, but the change in the API has nothing to do with the functionality of the method, it is purely an implementation detail. (For example, had `printCounter` been implemented with a loop, it wouldn't be necessary.)

Therefore, you want to hide this API from the consumer.

In order to really, properly hide this API, `printCounterAux` should however be an *inner function* of `printCounter`, like so:

```scala
def printCounter[X](xs: List[X]): Unit = {
  printCounterAux()

  def printCounterAux[X](xs: List[X] = xs, count: Int = 1): Unit = xs match {
    case Nil     => ()
    case y :: ys => {
      println("[%03d] %s".format(count, y))
      printCounterAux(ys, count + 1)
    }
  }
}

printCounter(List("the", "rain", "in", "spain"))
```

Note that in many cases, you will need to carry some sort of "state" around with you, and in a recursive function in a purely-functional language, a very convenient place to carry that state is in the arguments of the function. Therefore, you will often have to modify the parameter list in order to add a state parameter (like `count` in this case), which shouldn't be exposed to the consumer.